# Dowload zip file from blob with SAS link using azcopy

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I try to download a zip file from blob using the SAS link in powershell. I use the exact syntax as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-files#download-a-file) but I get the below error

```
failed to perform copy command due to error: cannot use directory as source without --recursive or a trailing wildcard (/*)
```

Below is the script

```
    .\azcopy.exe copy '<SAS link to file>' '<local file path>'
```

I use AzCopy version 10.3.3

Answer (score 0):

Your [linking article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-files#download-a-file) contains example commands that work with **Azure Files**. However, you mentioned you want to download a zip file from a blob in your question.

I can reproduce this issue when use blob storage but a file path in my Azure files. Please ensure that there is not any typo in your command, especially the blob storage URL and file storage URL.

[image]

If you want to download a file from blob storage, please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs#download-a-file).

**Syntax**

```
azcopy copy 'https://<storage-account-name>.<blob or dfs>.core.windows.net/<container-name>/<blob-path>?<SAS-token>' '<local-file-path>'
```

**Example**

```
azcopy copy 'https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myTextFile.txt?<SAS-token>' 'C:\myDirectory\myTextFile.txt'
```

**Example (hierarchical namespace)**

```
azcopy copy 'https://mystorageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myTextFile.txt?<SAS-token>' 'C:\myDirectory\myTextFile.txt'
```